# Is Puddletag not supported in 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I had Puddletag a few days ago, running on 19.10.  Yesterday I upgraded to 20.04, and now I don't have it.  Not listed in Software either.  What gives?

Comment: Problem being that support for Python 2 and QT4 has been dropped in 20.04 so PuddleTag will not run: https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues/300

Comment: This is the answer all right.  :-(
Thanks.  Want to repost it as an "answer", so I can upvote it?

Comment: @JimZipCode Done :)

Comment: I can heartily recommend Picard as an alternative though.

Answer (score 6):

In fact Puddletag in its present release will *not* be supported on Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04 as Puddletag needs to be updated to *both* QT5 and Python 3 (from Qt4 + Python 2).

The relevant bug reports can be seen here:

1. [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS = Qt4 + Python 2 removal #462](https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues/462) A bug report specific to the current Focal Fossa issue of the removal of Puddletag.
2. [Python 3 #300](https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues/300) The original plea for assistance by the Puddletag developer for assistance porting to  Python 3. Note that this a bug report / request *from 2016...*

Python 2 is of course still available on 20.04 (just not as default) but Puddletag will not work without the Python bindings pyqt4 and friends as well.

Sad days, but a nice replacement for Puddletag exists which works *perfectly* on 20.04: MusicBrainz Picard...

Comment: What I miss in Picard (or haven't found yet?) is a.o. the ability to display file attributes such as extension, codec, bitrate, channels etc. and use these attributes to better filter audio collections. Also, the workflow in Picard is less optimized for such tasks. I.e. when I need to change all track names in an album, I cannot simply move to the next file with down arrow. Instead, I need to constantly switch between the upper and lower part of the interface with lots of mouse movents and clicks. I'd be thrilled if someone could provide a Puddletag Snap or AppImage....

Comment: I find Picard *extremely* tedious compared to Puddletag's spreadsheet-like user interface.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a PPA that includes a recent build of `puddletag` that runs on Ubuntu 20.04+ distributions. It is hosted on launchpad and looks to be actively maintained.

According to the [puddletag main site](https://docs.puddletag.net/index.html),  the most recent `puddletag` version available is v2.0.1 (as of Aug. 29, 2020).

To install from  [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/apps), run the following commands from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install puddletag
```

If you choose to do this in Synaptic, add the following line in Settings -> Repositories -> Other Software -> Add...:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu focal main
```

---

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)
- [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

FYI. This PPA also has the latest version of the [audacious media player](https://audacious-media-player.org/) available as well.

Comment: I can confirm that Puddletag from this PPA also works with Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: @Zilk Thanks for confirming that it is working for you!

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE 2: The first version of PuddleTag based on Python3 and PyQt5 is here: https://github.com/puddletag/puddletag/releases/tag/2.0.1

I have not tested it yet, if anyone cares to share their experiences, please do. There doesn't seem to be a deb package nor AppImage just yet.

For the time being, working (but unofficial) PuddleTag AppImages can be found here: https://gofile.io/d/WQULBG (thanks @TSJNachos117 for your previous efforts).

More information on the AppImage (and how they got there): https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues/464

Answer (score 1):

After going through iGadget's answers, I followed some links, which lead me to more links, which, lead me to two different AppImages. For simplicity's sake, I decided to upload them both [HERE](https://archive.org/download/puddletag-appimages). Download, make executable, and enjoy!

PS: These two files print an awful lot of errors and warnings to the terminal. However, they seem to work nonetheless.

Credit goes [HERE](https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues/464#issuecomment-623119935) for the 1.1.1 version, and [HERE](https://github.com/keithgg/puddletag/issues/464#issuecomment-623121987) for the 1.2.0 version.

Comment: The 1.2.0 version you're using is even better than the link I provided, since in 'my' version the Extended Tag editor doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Whoops... The link to both AppImages seems to be dead. Can you re-upload?

Comment: Never mind, here's a new link: https://gofile.io/d/WQULBG

Comment: It seems gofile.io doesn't like keeping files on their site for too long. They only have so much disk space, so I guess it make sense for them to reject downloads that haven't had much activity. Luckily, I also uploaded to archive.org, as their track record is much better for long-term archiving (or so one would hope, given their domain name).

Comment: @iGadget: your link is now dead, too. :-(